# swig: how to access C array in Python

Tags: python, c, swig

I have following variable in C code, where I am storing some variables in 2D array. I am trying to access this array in python. I am getting following info..How can I retrieve data from that array

module.c

```
uin32_t  array_vaiable[10][100]
```

module.h

```
extern uint32_t array_variable[10][100]
```

module.i

```
%module mod
%{
    #include "module.h"
%}
%include "typemaps.i"
%include "module.h"
```

```
swig -python module.i

<Swig Object of type 'int (*)[100]'>
```

Comment: Exposing global variables in an interface is bad practice. You will always prefer to expose a function returning a variable on an interface. What you can do is cast to simple pointer and use `cpointer.i`

Answer (score 0):

It is in general a bad idea to expose global variables and you should use a function for exposing static information.

A very crude solution:

module.h

```
extern uint32_t array_variable[10][100]
uint32_t* cast(uint32_t (*a)[100]);
```

module.cpp

```
uint32_t array_variable[10][100] = {{}};
uint32_t* cast(uint32_t (*a)[100]) {
  return &(a[9][99]);
}
```

module.i

```
%module example
%{
     #include "test.h"
%}

%include "stdint.i"
%include "cpointer.i"
%pointer_functions(uint32_t, uint32p);

%include "test.h"
```

and do the following in Python to access e.g. the first element

```
import example
example.uint32p_assign(example.cast(example.cvar.array_variable),2)
example.uint32p_value(example.cast(example.cvar.array_variable))
```

If you want to access other elements, you can use `carrays.i` after that you cast'ed the 2D-array to a 1D-array.